# Does NPM INSTALL care which NODE version is available?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

We have a build server which has several `node` versions installed and managed with `nvm` and `node -v` is constantly changing.

I don't see any way to tell `npm` which NodeJS runtime I am building for so does `npm` or `npm i` care which version of `node` is currently available?

Can I build my NodeJS v20 apps and NodeJS v18 apps on the same server regardless of which node version is installed and/or which node version is currently active?

UPDATE: [this article](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/prevent-npm-install-for-not-supported-node-js-versions/) seems to suggest npm can check which node version is required (via the engines section of package.json) but npm will still build the application.

Comment: nvm does not only update your node version. It also updates your npm version to match the node version. So the answer to your question is yes, npm does care. The answer to your second question is yes, you can build multiple versions on the same server. In fact you can have multiple versions of node and npm run at the same time because you can have nvm changes per shell session (so each terminal window can have its own version of node and npm)

Comment: NVM aside - my understanding from the [npm blog](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/165273023140/supported-nodejs-versions-in-the-npm-cli.html) is that the latest version of npm supports any node version currently supported. So if I install the latest npm and nodejs20 it should be able to build v20 and v18 apps without needing nodejs v18 to actually be installed.

Comment: Your comment does seem correct however as nvm downgrades npm when switching to nodejs v18: `nvm use 20` -> `Now using node v20.6.1 (npm v9.8.1)` then `nvm use 18` > `Now using node v18.17.1 (npm v9.6.7)`

Comment: [nve](https://github.com/ehmicky/nve) looks like it would help in my case as it is not an OS alias and can thus be easily used during CI.

Answer (score 2):

`npm` not being a build tool in itself (only handles dependencies and executes scripts), you may refer to unspecified build command and executable?

> Our build pipeline is basically `npm i` followed by some custom `node script.js` then `npm test`, `npm prune`, `npm audit` etc.

- `npm test` just executes your [`scripts.test`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-test) command; if the underlying executable requires Node, it will use the binary specified in the `PATH`
- `npm prune` and `npm audit` work on your dependencies and their version, irrespective of Node
- `node script.js` obviously uses the corresponding Node version (here what is specified in the `PATH`)
- `npm install` will install the package dependencies (and development dependencies), according to their specified versions; *it is up to you to ensure compatibility of your dependencies version with your targeted Node version*; if they specify some Node [engines constraint](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#engines), and the latter is not met by the version in `PATH`, it will only produce a warning (unless you set the [`engine-strict`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/config#engine-strict) flag):

> Unless the user has set the `engine-strict` config flag, this field is advisory only and will only produce warnings when your package is installed as a dependency.

---

That being said, with `nvm` you can at least use a specific `node` and `npm` version, *for a single command*, irrespective of the current system, terminal session or default `node`/`npm` version of your build server, using [`nvm exec <nodeVersion> npm <command>`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#usage):

> you can run any arbitrary command in a subshell with the desired version of node

(Or its associated `npm` version)

For example:

```bash
nvm exec 18 npm install # Will use the appropriate npm version for Node v18, and will see that Node v18 if needing Node
```

It actually launches a subshell and `nvm use <version>` under the hood, and executes your command there. Therefore these Node and npm versions may differ from the rest of the machine shells.

For example if a dependency has a [`prepare`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) script that requires Node, it will get the version provided by `nvm exec <version>` after being `npm install`'ed.

Comment: Not sure what your first sentence/question meant... Also, we manage node versions on the server with nvm but our actual build does not use nvm (since it is a shell command and not a binary) we actually use the node or npm binary found with `nvm use 20 && which npm`

Comment: Smells like there is confusion in what you refer to as your build. Please clarify in your question.

Comment: Our build pipeline is basically `npm i` followed by some custom `node script.js` then `npm test`, `npm prune`, `npm audit` etc. These are each steps which run in sequence. Since multiple pipelines may run in parallel on the same machine, each pipeline on a different node version (but the same user) we cant just use nvm inside the pipeline to switch node versions. My current solution is to use the exact binary

Comment: You misunderstood this answer then: with `nvm exec`, you do not _change_ the node and npm version of the session, but only for the given command. For node, it ends up being the same as using the exact binary. For all other commands (including npm), it behaves _as if_ the node and npm versions were changed.

Comment: You can launch `nvm exec 18 npm --version` in parallel (with different requested versions) and see the effect.

Comment: OK, unfortunately nvm is not "CI Friendly" as it is not a binary on the $PATH but a command (bash function) which must be loaded for every step of the pipeline. I think what we are looking for is a way to run specific, synchronized version of npm, npx and node. If I specify `/usr/bin/npmv10` I want it to use `/usr/bin/nodev20` and not ``/usr/bin/node` which may be the wrong version.

Comment: I see. At this point, you might start thinking about running each build in a Docker container, which would provide a totally isolated and controlled environment then.